# Can I substitute in an entire function during u-substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

If I have a function such as:

∫1/(²+1)x

can I u-substitute it to be:

(1/2x)*∫du/(u)

So I have made du=2x? It seems that most textbooks use numbers but don't cover what I have done above, and I don't see why what I have done is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take $\frac{1}{2x}$ outside of the integral, since it's not a constant. From $u=x^2+1$ you get $x = \pm\sqrt{u-1}$. So in the case with the plus sign, for example, you would get
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x^2+1}
= \int \frac{du}{2 u \sqrt{u-1}}
.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that this also works for integrals with bounds. By substituting $u=x^2+1$ it follows $du=2x dx$ so that

$$ \int_a^b \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx = \int_{a^2+1}^{b^2+1} \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{u-1}}du.$$